# python select key in dict

Tags: python-2.7, solr, python-3.6

have a simple request to Solr below

```
response = requests.get("http://localhost:8080/solr/select?fl=id,title,description,keywords,author&q=domain:mydomain.com&rows=10&indent=on&wt=json&omitHeader=true")
result = response.json()
print type(result)
print result
print response.text
```

the above code fives me the following output

the type

```
<type 'dict'>
```

the dict contents

```
{u'response': {u'start': 0, u'numFound': 1, u'docs': [{u'keywords': u'my keywords listed here', u'id': u'project.websiteindex.abe919664893e46eef21aacb1360948ae836a756faa28e2063a4a92ef4273630', u'description': u'my site description isted here.', u'title': u'my site title'}]}}
```

and below the better readable vesion

```
{
  "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "description":"my site description isted here.",
        "title":"my site title",
        "keywords":"my keywords listed here",
        "id":"project.websiteindex.abe919664893e46eef21aacb1360948ae836a756faa28e2063a4a92ef4273630"}]
  }}
```

executing:

```
print(result['response']['numFound'])
```

will give me the very useful output of

```
1
```

Very nice and all, but obviously i would like to get something like

```
print(result['response']['title'])

my site title
```

So my question, how do i get my values of title,description and keywords as keys
How do i select them using this format, or how do i get my desired values in a better dict format?

p.s.
stuck wioth an old setup here with python 2.7 and solr 3.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the values you are addressing are fields of an array element, you have to address the element first.

Try something like:

```
result['response']['docs'][0]['title']
```

Comment: yup, took me two days two be able to figure out what wasn't working and formulate the problem. you saved me another week, thank you, thank you